# How do I say IF class #1 on left, if class #2 on right in loop

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress, loops

I have a loop in wordpress that will spit out two classes. One class photos, the other is video. Once a new photo or video is added, it just adds below the last div.

```
Example:   
Photos  
Photos  
Video  
Photos  
Video
```

So what I need to happen is, I need all photos to the left and all videos to the right. I already tried using `Float:left` and `Float:right` and `clear:left;` and `clear:right;` and it's not working as I planned since the divs are set at 50%. If not cleared, they go in rows photos, photos, then new row, video, photos.

I was thinking there is some PHP I can use, saying IF photos, be in this column, if videos be in the other column.

I tried the following:

```
 .photos {
float: left;
width: 50%;
display: block;
clear: left;
 }
 .video {
float:right;
width:50%;
display: block;
clear:none;

 }
```

and also:

```
.photos {
float: left;
width: 50%;
display: block;
clear: none;
 }
 .video {
float:right;
width:50%;
display: block;
clear:none;

 }
```

I just want the videos to go to right and the photos to the left from top to bottom. I can't separate the two in two different DIV's because they are in a loop.

Here is the array:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_post' ); ?>

  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <div class="thumbl">
  <?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
  } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="date"><?php printf( __( '%1$s', 'buddypress' ), get_the_date(), get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?></div>
      <div class="post-content">
     <h2 class="posttitle"><a href="../../plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e( 'Permanent Link to', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

  <div class="entry">
    <?php the_excerpt( __( 'Read the rest of this entry &rarr;', 'buddypress' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><p>' . __( 'Pages: ', 'buddypress' ), 'after' => '</p></div>', 'next_or_number' => 'number' ) ); ?>
 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_post' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And the code that I get for example only:

```
<div id="post-175" class="post-175 photos type-photos status-publish hentry category-media"></div>
<div id="post-176" class="post-175 photos type-photos status-publish hentry category-media"></div>
<div id="post-177" class="post-175 video type-photos status-publish hentry category-media"></div>
<div id="post-178" class="post-175 photos type-photos status-publish hentry category-media"></div>
<div id="post-179" class="post-175 video type-photos status-publish hentry category-media"></div>
<div id="post-180" class="post-175 photos type-photos status-publish hentry category-media"></div>
```

Notice the second class of each Photos and Videos

To answer my own question, I found a solution!!!

Place this code above the loop

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Put this below the div's just outside the loop

```
<div class="photodiv"><div></div></div>
 <script>$("div.photos").wrapAll($(".photodiv"));</script>
```

This wraps a new div around anything with the class .photos which I can float to the left!

Comment: if the div classes are different for photos or videos, i assume they are, then it's just a styling issue that needs attention. If you post some CSS here it would be helpful.

Comment: You can separate the two and should. Show me what the array looks like that holds them.

Comment: Just edited the main question and added the array.

Comment: I'm more interest in what George has to say. I think a solution would be a PHP code or Javascript code to separate them in the array.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, photos to the left and videos to the right, this could be a solution:

```
<style>
.main {width:800px;}
.main > div >span {clear:both;float:left;}
.video {width:400px;float:right;"}
.photo {width:400px;float:left;"}
</style>

<div class="main">
    <div class="video">
        <span>Video1</span>
        <span>Video2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <span>Photos1</span>
        <span>Photos2</span>
        <span>Photos3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the problem is that the photos and videos are mixed together since they are in a loop. They have <div class="photos">CONTENT</div>,<div class="photos">CONTENT</div>, <div class="video">CONTENT</div>, <div class="photos">CONTENT</div>, <div class="video">CONTENT</div>

Answer (score 0):

What i would do to easy things out is the following
1. check the post class 
2. if post class equal videos put them in a video array else put them in photos array
3. now i have to array with photos and videos which i can display wherever i want 
take a look at this

```
        <?php
        $photos = array();
        $videos = array();
        $post_class = array();

        ?>


        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

         <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_post' ); ?>


            <?php 
            $post_class = get_post_class(); 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $post_img = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); 
            }

            ?>


          <?php 
          if (strpos($post_class[0], 'photos')) {
                $photos[] = "<div id='{$post->ID}' class='{$post_class}>'
            <div class='thumbl'>
            {$post_img} 
            </div>
            <div class='date'>
            ". get_the_date() . "
            </div>
            <div class='post-content'>
             <h2 class='posttitle'>
                    <a href='../../plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/". get_permalink() . "' rel='bookmark' title='" . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ."'>
                    " . get_the_title() . "
                    </a>
             </h2> 
             <div class='entry'>
            " . get_the_excerpt() . " 
            " . get_page_link($post->ID) . "
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          ";
          }
          if (strpos($post_class[0], 'video')){
                    $videos[] = "<div id='{$post->ID}' class='{$post_class}>'
            <div class='thumbl'>
            {$post_img} 
            </div>
            <div class='date'>
            ". get_the_date() . "
            </div>
            <div class='post-content'>
             <h2 class='posttitle'>
                    <a href='../../plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/". get_permalink() . "' rel='bookmark' title='" . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ."'>
                    " . get_the_title() . "
                    </a>
             </h2> 
             <div class='entry'>
            " . get_the_excerpt() . " 
            " . get_page_link($post->ID) . "
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          ";
          }

          ?>


          <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_post' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php /** now you hava separated the  videos and images so you can put them in different divs  outside the loop**/ ?>

        <div id="videos" style="width:50%; float:left;">
            <?php foreach ($photos as $photo) {
                echo $photo;
            } ?>
        </div>
        <div id="photos" style="width:50%; float:right;">
            <?php foreach ($videos as $video) {
                echo $video;
            } ?>
        </div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt